# Signal problem with Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5630 mobile

Tags: connection-issues, mobile-network, samsung-galaxy-y

I am using Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5630 phone with IDEA network provider. I am having signal loss problems many times a times. When I try to make a call, it says "Network unavailable". I though this might be the problem IDEA network, but it was not. I tried checking the same sim card in another mobile and it's working fine, this issue is  being observed mostly for every 4-5 minutes. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Different network providers may use different masts.

The company of the second sim will have a stronger presence in your area than the company from the first sim.

Therefore, the ideal move would be to get yourself a sim from the same provider of the second sim.

I hope this helps, 
Nicholas

Answer (score 0):

Your phone probably is fixed in 3G mode or is in auto 3G/GSM mode. I suggest you to switch to GSM only mode. That way you won't face a network problem.

> Go to Settings > Wireless and Networks > Mobile networks > Network
>   Mode

Select GSM only from that menu.

Also try going to Network Operators from the mobile network menu and try selecting a network manually.